Are principal G-bundles over a fat point / local artinian algebra trivial?
According to Jarod Alper's manuscript (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/moduli.pdf, Def. B.1.47), a principal G-bundle over a $k$-scheme $T$ (for a field $k$) consists of

a $k$-scheme $P$ with a $G$-action $\sigma: G \times_k P \longrightarrow P$,

a surjective smooth $G$-invariant morphism $P \longrightarrow T$,


such that the morphism $(\sigma, id_P):G\times_k P \longrightarrow P\times_T P$ is an isomorphism.
If $k$ is algebraically closed (perhaps of characteristic $0$ for simplicity's sake), then principal $G$-bundles over $Spec \;k$ are trivial, i.e. $P \cong G$. As a result, the groupoid of $k$-points, $[X/G](k)$, of the quotient stack $[X/G]$ correspond to groupoid of orbits of points in $X$ under $G$.
My question is whether we can say something similar for $A$-points of the quotient stack for $A$ a local artinian algebra, i.e. $Spec \; A$ is a so-called fat point.
Is a principal G-bundle over $Spec \, A$ always trivial? Do they correspond to the orbits of an $A$-point of $X$ under $G$? Or is this too much to ask?

PS, your last sentence of the first paragraph is note quite right. One has that $X/G$ corresponds to the action groupoid $[X(k)/G(k)]$ (i.e., the groupoid with points $X(k)$ and with morphisms $x\to y$ those $g\in G(k)$ such that $gx=y$).

@AlexYoucis Yes, I meant the groupoid of orbits of X under G. Of course this is equivalent to the action groupoid that you write. I will edit it.

Presumably you mean that $A$ is a local Artinian algebra with algebraically closed residue field $k$. If $k$ is not assumed algebraically then of course this is false by taking $A=k=\mathbb{Q}$ and something like $G=\mathrm{Res}^1_{\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}}\,\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Q}(i)}$ (i.e., the units with norm $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$).
If you meant to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, then the answer is yes. This would of course follow if the map $H^1(A,G)\to H^1(k,G)$ were an injection, as the latter set is trivial. Does this injectivity hold?
In fact something much more general holds which I would like to advertise, as it should be more well-known.

Theorem (see [CB, Theorem 2.1.6]) Suppose $(A,I)$ is a Henselian pair and that $G$ is a quasi-separated and smooth group $A$-scheme. Then, the natural map $H^1(A,G)\to H^1(A/I,G)$ is injective. If $G$ is actually  quasi-affine, this map is a bijection.

For instance, if $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $A$ then the pair $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is Henselian (see Tag 01SJ) and so as $G$ is smooth and quasi-separated (as holds for any finite type group $k$-scheme when $k$ is characteristic $0$, e.g., see
[M, Proposition 1.22] and [M, Theorem 3.23]) we see that $H^1(A,G)\hookrightarrow H^1(k,G)=\{\ast\}$.
[CB] Bouthier, A. and Česnavičius, K., 2022. Torsors on loop groups and the Hitchin fibration. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup, 55, pp.791-864.
[M] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.

I indeed meant with residue field the base field k!
Which cohomology do you mean exactly by H^1(A,G)? Unfortunately I do not know how it relates to principal G-bundles (a link that I can check out would already be great).
I was hoping to find a simple direct/algebraic argument, similar to how you have on for G-bundles over spec k.

@Lilolance Just take the $H^1(A,G)$ to mean $G$-torsors. I think it’s technically for the fppf topology, but it’s the same for the etale topology since $G$ is smooth.

@Lilolance I mean you can give a ‘simple argument’, for which this result of Alexis and Kestutis is a vast generalization of. Suppose that $P$ is a $G$-torsor over $A$. As $G$ is smooth, so is $A$. As $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is Henselian, and $P(k)$ is non-empty (as $P_k$ must be a trivial $G$-torsor) you know by Hensel’s lemma that $P(A)$ is non-empty (as $P(A)\to P(k)$ is surjective).

this is great, this indeed solves it without having to introduce etale of fppf cohomology
